# Count non-zero entries in each column of a matrix

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5; 1 1 6 1 2; 0 0 9 0 1]

A =

     1     2     3     4     5
     1     1     6     1     2
     0     0     9     0     1
```

How can I count the number of non-zero entries for each column? For example the desired output for this matrix would be:

2, 2, 3, 2, 3

I am not sure how to do this as `size`, `length` or `numel` do not appear to meet the requirements. Perhaps it would be best to remove zero entries first?

Comment: @natan - I don't agree think this is a duplicate.  The OP wants to count how many non-zero elements are **per column**.  The duplicate is seeking to count how many non-zero elements there are **overall**.

Comment: well, I don't see the big difference, if one understand the answers there the transition to this question is straight forward... I see there's a wish to reopen, so I wont be mean an give my vote for that too.

Comment: @natan - I see what you're seeing and understand.  But I do think that the questions are fundamentally different, even though they're based on using similar techniques.  Thanks for choosing to reopen though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply

```
> A ~= 0
ans =

   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   1   0   1

> sum(A ~= 0, 1)
ans =

   2   2   3   2   3
```

Comment: This is strictly not necessary, but I always prefer to include the second parameter stating which dimension you want to sum along. The default is summing per column, as in your answer. But consider a case where the number of rows is 1, now you sum will only be a single number. If the size of the matrix changes between calls (which it often does), that might cause bugs. Thus, IMHO a slightly better approach would be `sum(A ~= 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution I can suggest that isn't very speed worthy for dense matrices but quite fast for sparse matrices (thanks @user1877862!).  This also would mimic how one might do this in a compiled language, like C or Java, and perhaps for research purposes too.  First find the row and column locations that are non zero, then do a histogram on just the column locations to count the frequency of how often you see a non-zero in each column.  In other words:

```
[~,col] = find(A ~= 0);
counts = histc(col, 1:size(A,2));
```

`find` outputs the row and column locations of where a matrix satisfies some Boolean condition inside the argument of the function.  We ignore the first output as we aren't concerned with the row locations.

The output we get is:

```
counts =

     2
     2
     3
     2
     3
```

Comment: This is absolutely speed-worthy if A is sparse. Thanks!

Comment: @user1877862 I've never benchmarked the code... I have only speculated but very nice to know it's fast for sparse matrices. I can see that it would be fast because of the call to `find`. Thanks!